# Read php array in java from php source code

Tags: java, php, arrays

I have one desktop application in which I want to read php file using IO class. And then parse php variable/array on my java class. Is there any pattern that is used in java using Pattern and Matcher class to extract php variable?

Below is sample php code with temp.php

```
<?php $temp = array("test"=>'test', 'test44'=>"TEST44");?>
```

I want to read temp array variable in java and from source code not from running application?  Is there any API avaialble or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to parse PHP variables from Java? Can't you instead use XML or JSON?

Comment: JSON is good option but this is not web application.  I want to use php array variable in java desktop application.